# What am I doing wrong with curves following terrain?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

Not sure if you can see it that good, but there's a path following the road on the texture, the cursor 3d thing is where the path starts and that's where I put my small road model (5x5 meters, something like that).

For some reason however, once I apply the curve modifier, the road teleports of map, then I add arrays and even once it reaches the terrain, it curves the right way, but it is tens of meters to the left from where it's supposed to be. So what am I doing wrong? Do I need to adjust the relative offset numbers and if so, why?

I'm a beginner, but I've made roads before the same way and I never had this issue before.

Btw, one thing that came to mind is that the road for some reason starts at the scene center, but no, the center of the scene is somewhere in the middle of the terrain, so I really have no idea why it teleports in the middle of nowhere.

[image]

Comment: Where are the origin points of the curve object and of the track? (before adding modifier). It's not clear what do you mean by "scene center" and how is it related, try applying scale and rotation for curve and track and in Edit mode of the curve reset Radius of the curve points to 1 (if it isn't)

Comment: Which addon you have used to make that terrain

Comment: @MrZak The origin point of the curve (nurbs path) is the 3d cursor, which you can see here where the terrain begins. By scene center I meant the "center of Blenders world" (press shift + s , cursor to center, that one :) ) , you lost me after that, I am a total noob, so explain scale and rotation if it's not a problem. The path itself follows the terrain perfectly, there is no issues with that, I tried nudging relative offset numbers for the 3d model of the road after adding a curve modifier, but everything other than x 1.000 (as in the screenshot) just breaks everything.

Comment: @atek None, Sketchup 2017 to download the terrain in Sketchup, then I exploded the terrain and made a new component in SK and then exported it as a OBJ file.

Comment: Update, I figured it out, the "center" point of the Nurbs path was in the middle of the terrain, I moved the 3d model of the road there and after adding the curve and array modifiers, it fixed the problem, so the problem was that the 3d model was far from the nurbs path's center.

Comment: It's great if you fixed the problem, you could answer your own question with some details and screenshots. For information see [applying scale and rotation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html#apply) and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation about scale and rotation.